# Pass character argument and evaluate

Tags: r

I have a logical operator and a numeric value I want to pass as a single element to a statement in a function (I hear hundreds of R users groaning; I never do this but have a situation I feel it's ok to).

```
DF <- mtcars
overlap = "> 2"
as.numeric(rowSums(DF[, 1:6]) overlap)
```

How can I make the third line work like:

```
as.numeric(rowSums(DF[, 1:6]) > 2)
```

I know it's likely `eval` and `parse` but never use them so don't really understand how to use them here.

Comment: Can you pass overlap as a list containing the comparison and the threshold?

Comment: @mnel No because overlap can mean even more things. It has to be the character input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like

```
Olap <- unlist(strsplit( overlap, " "))
Thresh <- as.numeric(Olap[2])
Comp <- match.fun(Olap[1])
Comp(rowSums(DF[,1:6]), Thresh)
```

An alternative is eval and parse as you suggested

```
What <- rowSums( DF[,1:6])

 textcall <- sprintf(" What %s", overlap)

 exprcall <- parse(text = textcall)

 eval( exprcall)
```

Comment: I think you need the `unlist` but this may be the approach I take.  Let's see what else the think tank has.

Comment: thanks I was really interested at the start in how to use `eval` `parse` and it's been informative but I think the 1st approach you suggest may be better.  +1  I'll give it a bit for people to respond but I already have the function set up using your first suggestion.

Comment: 4 upvotes and no other solutions tell me this is the check mark.  I already uploaded the function to github.  Works nicely.  Thanks for your idea.

Comment: That second option currently does not work. Please remember to correct it when you are in front of a computer :-)  Or maybe someone else can?

Comment: @mb3041023 -- The first example is now fixed. The second works for me (unchanged)

Comment: Me too. That'll teach me to try coding so long after my bed time. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7):

You have to convert the entire expression to a string, then convert the parsed text to an expression. 
Finally, call eval() on the expression.

eg:

```
overlap <- "> 2"

# Convert to string
exprAsString <- paste0("as.numeric(rowSums(DF[, 1:6]) ", overlap, ")")

# Convert to expression, using parse
expr <- as.expression(parse(text=exprAsString))

# Then call eval()
eval(expr)
```

**Confirming It Works:**

```
identical(eval(expr), as.numeric(rowSums(DF[, 1:6]) > 2))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

It strikes me that, while @mnel 's solution is good, this is a situation that could be solved by creating a dummy function inside your main function and using your input string (`overlap`) as an argument to modify `body(dummy_function)` . That could be a lot  cleaner.